# What type of flight plan are ZeroG experience flights?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

According to flightradar24, the ZeroG experience flights are on an IFR flightplan climbing into Class A airspace. Do they file lat long fixes for the flightplans or do they use fixes to guide the flights? Are they assigned block altitudes to do the "Zero G" simulations? In this case, the aircraft is N794AJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An operator conducting regular operations like that will normally negotiate an operating area or areas, with the corners defined by lat/long waypoints that can be easily programmed into an FMS, with the appropriate ATC unit, with a written agreement that has the parameters and requirements clearly defined. Manufacturers use such designated test areas for production test flights, so it would be a similar situation for an operator doing ballistic arc flights.

When you do a trip into the operating area, you just file a normal IFR flight plan from the departure airport to a fix or fixes or possibly an airway that leads into the area. You may include an altitude block in your flight plan, or you may just get an initial altitude clearance for entry, and request the block once you are there.

Once in the operating area, and with a block altitude clearance, you are free to move anywhere within the lateral boundaries, and within the altitude block, without having to talk to ATC, until you're ready to leave, or unless ATC calls you to modify your clearance with some kind of restriction to accommodate traffic they want to pass through or nearby.